# Как из pthread выполнить функцию в главный поток

Tags: linux, c, pthread

Как из pthread выполнить функцию в главный поток.
У меня есть вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

FILE* file;
void* thr() {
    ftruncate(fileno(file),5);
    fflush(file);
}
int main() {
    file = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thr,NULL);
    ftruncate(fileno(file),10);
    fflush(file);
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);

}
```

Мне нужно чтоб из thr() в определённый момент приостановить основной, а потом в другом моменте запустить

Comment: Вангую, вы на самом деле хотите, чтобы некие действия в 2-х потоках выполнялись скоординированно. Обычно для этого достаточно mutex-ов

Comment: А можете пример реализации?